# What is uWSGI master mode?

Tags: python, uwsgi

What are the benefits of running uWSGI in master mode if I'm only running a single app? Does master mode offer process management benefits that make it more reliable than, say, running via Upstart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

upstart is only a process manager, the uWSGI master has access to lot of memory areas of workers (well it is the opposite indeed) so it can make truly monitoring of the behaviour of workers, in addition to this it allows graceful reloading, exports statistics and dozens of other things. Running without it is not a good idea from various point of views.

Comment: i thought that memory-report and stats were enough to export stats.  Are there additional monitoring stats available when using master = true