# What is the uWSGI master process for?

Tags: uwsgi

What is the uWSGI master process for?

and/or where can I read more about it?

I have found zero documentation for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is uWSGI master mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20197259/what-is-uwsgi-master-mode)

Answer (score 12):

You can find some information about master [here](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Glossary.html?highlight=master) and [here](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/articles/TheArtOfGracefulReloading.html)

Generally speaking, master file is responsible for graceful reloading your app server (so there is as little as possible down time when you're reloading your app), it manages preforking and enables threading for app instances. It also manages some advanced logging features and keeps your app instances up and running (when one of instance crashes, master will re-launch it). It probably also manages harakiri mode (it kills hanged workers).

Generally speaking, using master is recommended for your apps, unless you're using emperor.

Running emperor (not vassals, but emperor by itself) with master process is recommended only if you need some of benefits that master gives, for example advanced logging. You can also skip master for your vassals, because emperor will do some of work that normally vassal does, but not all of it. I personally use master for vassals.

Comment: @JohnBachir Without master, preforking could work. threading works with `--threads N` or `--enable-threads`, it means your daemon thread could be run.